# AJAX null parameter in controller action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want pass values from my view to a controller action however every time i do the parameter is null. I've seen multiple posts about the same things but can't quite seem to get it right.. my code is below

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetTest(string data)
    {
        var jSon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(channles[0]);

        return Json(jSon);
    }
```

View (AJAX) code

```
function testAjax() {

        $("#searchButton1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTest", "DataGridWebApi")',
                data: { data: "test" },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

I hit the breakpoint in my controller action but the parameter is always null. I've also tried changing my controller action to accept an object instead of a string but nothing seems to work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is this CORE or MVC?

Comment: This is asp mvc targeting .net Core

Comment: @Steve that works!! Thank you! What is the reason for this? Because it's a single string and not an object? If you post as an answer i'll mark as correct.

Comment: I think it's because it's expecting form data, not json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes. You do need `[FromBody]` on the param:

```
public IActionResult GetTest([FromBody]string data)
```

Then, you need to send just the string, as JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify("test")
```

That may seem a little weird, but without `JSON.stringify` it will be sent as just `test`, and you need `"test"`. In short, you're sending a string with a JSON content type, so it must be a *JSON string*.

Comment: Chris, Thanks!! it seems I've been in the middle of both approaches when doing this, I've marked this as the correct answer for the explanation. Is there anywhere i can read more on this as a general topic? I'd like to pass object rather than a single string but thought this would be a good starting point..

Comment: Ironically, `string` is harder, here, since JSON is *object* notation, and isn't really intended to be used for just a single string. That's why you have to take more care to handle the string properly. With an object things work much more naturally.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the line : `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` should make it work. Just yesterday I had the exact same problem. We have a standard way of doing JSON calls and someone had inserted this line too, causing the object not to bind at the controller.

Comment: This will work, but it's important to note that you're switching to sending `x-www-form-urlencoded`, then. In other words, it's being sent as a traditional form post. Some clients may need that explicitly applied.

Comment: Thats the one.. thank you very much! I'll look into what contentType does as i'm still fairly new to the front end.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You are correct. The application we use is from early MVC where we use `(FormCollection form)` in the signature, then we use `Deserialize<WhateverObject>(form["whateverdata"])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[FromBody]` before `string data` in the controller parameters. [Here is why](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.. i did try that before when i tried passing an object instead of a single string.

Comment: @JoshuaAshton Try removing the `dataType` from the ajax