# Passing parameter to MVC Action via Ajax always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I looked at related questions to to form my ajax request but I can't figure out why this isn't working as the param is always null in the acion

I've done a console.log to check that item in 'data: { data: item }' has a value

```
 //action
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMedia(string data)
 {

 $("#mediaTable").on('click', 'td:nth-child(7)', function () {
        var item = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        $("#MediaToDownload").val(item);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteMedia", "Home")',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: { data: item },
            success: function (data) {
                location.href = data;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Ryn901,If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer, it will be helpful to people who have the same problem later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send just the string, as JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify(item)
```

Comment: still getting null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301463/ajax-null-parameter-in-controller-action